# Uploading large mysql database on AWS RDS using putty - 'MySQL server has gone away'

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Im using Amazon Web services and I've setup EC2 and RDS and installed apache, php, mysql, phpmyadmin.

I can import small sql files (I also setup worpdress and imported a sql db for that -fine) but when I try to import a 200mg sql file using putty I get

> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 186: MySQL server has gone away'

After doing some research it seemed increasing **max_allowed_packet**, **wait_timeout** and **net_read_timeout** in **DB Parameter Groups** would help but it didnt (I did reboot after making changes, I also set those to their maximum allowed values using RightScale dashboard).

Is there anything else I should be aware of that might be causing this?

I also tried bigdump.php with no luck.

I presume loads of people upload large mysql databases using aws so this is kinda driving me crazy.

Comment: Are you trying this from the EC2 machines or from your local machine?

Comment: Im trying from my local machine using Putty.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had the same problem:

1. Go to your RDS Dashboard and click **Parameter Groups**.
2. Click **Create DB Parameter Group**, name it something like 'LargeImport', (making sure the DB Parameter Group Family you select matches your instance version) and edit the parameters.
3. Increase the '**max_allowed_packet**' on 'LargeImport' to accommodate your import size (Valid values are 1024-1073741824).
4. Increase the '**wait_timeout**' parameter to accommodate your import size. (Valid values are 1-31536000 seconds).
5. Save your changes.
6. Click **Instances** in the left column and select your instance.
7. Click **Instance Actions** and choose **Modify**.
8. Change the **Parameter Group** to your new 'LargeImport' group and click **Continue**.
9. Click 'Modify DB Instance'.
10. Once the change has completed, click **Instance Actions** again and reboot your instance.

Once your instance has rebooted, you should be able to do larger sql imports.

**Once you've completed your import, switch your instance parameter group back to the default parameter group and reboot it again.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like a charm !!

Comment: If your import file is produced from `mysqldump` then make sure your `max_allowed_packet` value in `my.cnf` <= the same value for that parameter in the RDS parameter group value. Otherwise you'll get the gone away error.

Comment: MAKE SURE YOU REBOOT. A simple modification is not enough.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but changing the max_allowed_packet to something large (i.e. 32000000 =~ 32MB) and rebooting did.

Comment: No need to reboot. Once the Parameter Group has been assigned to the instance, any changes made to it are immediate.

Comment: Rebooting was needed for me I'm afraid.  How long did it take to reflect your new value without rebooting?

Comment: Any instance using the updated parameter group will automatically have their status changed to `modifying`, which you can view from the instance dashboard. It should only take a couple of minutes before the status returns to `available`, at which point the new values will be in effect.

Comment: In my case, a reboot was required. I saw that changes were applied, but until RDS was rebooted - the import failed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html), this often has to do with timeouts. While it is hard to diagnose this, I could think of a possible workaround: fire up an EC2 instance in the same region as your RDS server (or use an existing one that you already have  - a micro one or a small one will do), upload your big SQL dump there for example using SFTP, install the MySQL client libraries and upload your file from there. This will ensure a faster import speed between your mysql client and your RDS instance.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My EC2 and RDS are in the same region, which is Ireland, I am in South Africa. I did upload the database to the server using sftp and then used putty to install it but it still times out (this procedure does work with smaller databases eg. 20 megs). Maybe there are other values in the db parameters group I need to change?