# Importing database for amazon rds: ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 667: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: amazon-rds

While importing a database to my amazon rds instance i've been issued the following error:

> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 667: MySQL server has gone away

I went ahead and tried changing the `interative_timeout` setting to a larger number. However, it'll only let me set that for a session and amazon doesn't allow it to be set for global sessions.

How do i import a larger database into my amazon's rds instance?

Comment: did you finally find a workout for this? I'm getting the same problem

Comment: This helped others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23832059/1252307

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.AnySource.html) gives instructions on how to import large datasets. Typically, the best method is to create flat files and import them in to your RDS instance.

I recently completed a migration of a database over 120GB in size from a physical server to RDS. I dumped each table in to a flat CSV file, then split the larger files in to multiple 1GB size parts. I then imported each table in to RDS.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your RDS DB sizing settings by using the parameter group settings.  Most MSQL settings are in there.  It will require a restart of the instance however.  The setting you want is max_allowed_packet and you need to not only set it with the client, but on the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, mind you my databases weren't very large (largest one was 1.5G).

First dump your existing database(s):

```
mysqldump [database_name] --master-data=2 --single-transaction --order-by-primary -uroot -p | gzip > /mnt/dumps/[database_name].sql.gz
```

You can then transfer this file to an Amazon EC2 instance that has permission to access your RDS instance using something like [scp](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php). Once the file is located on your Amazon EC2 instance you should extract it using:

```
gzip [database_name].sql.gz -d
#you should now have a file named [database_name].sql in your directory.
mysql -uroot -p -h=[rds-instance]
source [database_name].sql
```

It should then start importing. This information is located in their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html).