# AWS-RDS Max Allowed Packet Value Cant Be Changed

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL database in Amazon RDS setup right now that needs to be able to act as a database and also be able to store some flat files.

It was working just fine for a while until I noticed it wasn't storing anything over 1MB... and I couldn't figure out why. So I dove deeper into RDS and learned about **parameter groups**. It seems to be a subset of configurations for the database itself, and so I figured it was the `max_allowed_packet` value was the problem and I set it to a higher value.

However, I was still unable to make uploads over 1MB so then I realized there was another parameter by the name of `mysqlx_max_allowed_packet` and its value is set to about 1MB, but I am unable to change it.

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this or if it is possible?

Comment: `mysqlx_max_allowed_packet` is not important unless you are using the [X protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/x-plugin-options-system-variables.html), so is probably unrelated.  I would suggest that you need to step back and consider that `max_allowed_packet`-related errors are not silent errors.  Exceptions are supposed to be thrown.  If your code is ignoring them (such as in languages that require you to check a return value to see if a query succeeded), and silently discarding large values, you need to find and fix that problem and then react as such error messages may dictate.

Comment: Hmm... 1MB is as small as I ever see `max_allowed_packet`.  16MB is typical; 1GB is not unheard of.

Comment: This may help [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23832059/3266552]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope these steps help.

1. Go to your RDS Dashboard and click **Parameter Groups**.
2. Click **Create DB Parameter Group**, name it something like 'LargeImport', (making sure the DB Parameter Group Family you select matches your instance version) and edit the parameters.
3. Increase the '**max_allowed_packet**' on 'LargeImport' to accommodate your import size (Valid values are 1024-1073741824).
4. Increase the '**wait_timeout**' parameter to accommodate your import size. (Valid values are 1-31536000 seconds).
5. Save your changes.
6. Click **Instances** in the left column and select your instance.
7. Click **Instance Actions** and choose **Modify**.
8. Change the **Parameter Group** to your new 'LargeImport' group and click **Continue**.
9. Click 'Modify DB Instance'.
10. Once the change has completed, click **Instance Actions** again and reboot your instance.

Once your instance has rebooted, you should be able to do larger SQL imports.

**Once you've completed your import, switch your instance parameter group back to the default parameter group and reboot it again.**

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, because everything state here would work, my ultimate problem ended up being configuration issues I had with NginX, I didn't even consider it because I had never setup the webserver but was confused when I couldnt see any access logs on my rds instance

Comment: If you have a reader you can failover to it, then reboot the old writer and failover again. With you'll reduce the downtime.

Answer (score 2):

I reccomend you to test if your change take effect , so go on mysqlworkbench on your mysql instance and launch the query :

show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';

If it isn't then you can start change it to 64 MB for example ( tune the parameter to your requirements but take in mind that 1GB for aws is the max limitation). Remember also after modify RDS instance you should reboot to apply your changes.

Comment: Ahhh rebooting.....

Comment: The best first choice 4 everything :D